# F# array member value is lost after constructor

Tags: arrays, f#, constructor, sequence

I am a F# newbie and I have a (probably simple) question.

The purpose of the code below is to copy the values from the sequence (bytestream) into the array `myarray_`, keeping the size of the array `thesize`, and having other elements set to zero.

I can see the values being copied in the for loop. But after leaving the constructor, the debugger shows that `myarray_` of the newly constructed object contains all zeros!

I am using VS2012. Thanks.

**EDIT**: The size of the recipient array is always bigger than the size of the incoming sequence.

**EDIT**: The object of this SomeClass is actually instantiated as a member of an outer class. Here it is, along with more context in 'SomeClass'.
When the main program calls OuterClass.Func, the "cp" objects gets created, and the array gets properly populated. When the code leaves the ctor the array either contains all zeros, or it *has* size zero (see comments below).

** **SOLVED?** ** : I changed "cp" from "member" to "let mutable"... it seems to work now. Not sure to understand why.

```
type SomeClass(thesize, bytestream : seq<byte>) = class
    let mutable myarray_ = Array.create<byte> thesize 0uy

    do
        let mutable idx = 0
        for v in bytestream do
            myarray_.[idx] <- v
            idx <- idx + 1

    member x.Func(index) = // consumes myarray_.[index] and neighbor values


type OuterClass(thesize, bytestream) = class
    member x.cp : SomeClass = new SomeClass(thesize, bytestream)
    member x.Func(index) =
        x.cp.Func(index)
```

Comment: "*I changed "cp" from "member" to "let mutable"... it seems to work now. Not sure to understand why.*" With `member`, `cp` is a get-only property that returns a new `SomeClass` object upon each property fetch. With `let mutable`, `cp` is a single variable that is initialized a single time. Note that `mutable` is not necessary for this to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declare `myarray_` as a mutable value, so it's possible to assign it to a newly created array somewhere in your code. You should not use `mutable` keyword because you want to update array elements, not change the array to a new one.

Assume that `thesize` is bigger than length of `bytestream`:

```
type SomeClass(thesize, bytestream : seq<byte>) =
    let myarray_ = [| yield! bytestream
                      for i in (Seq.length bytestream)..(thesize-1) -> 0uy |]
    ....
```

**EDIT:**

With

```
member x.cp : SomeClass = new SomeClass(thesize, bytestream)
```

you essentially instantiate a new instance of `SomeClass` each time the property is used. Therefore, you will not see the effects of `x.Func` on the old `SomeClass`. What you probably want is:

```
type OuterClass(thesize, bytestream) =
    let cp = new SomeClass(thesize, bytestream)
    member x.cp = cp
```

where the instance is only constructed once in the default constructor.

Comment: as I see in original code it has assumption that thesize is greater that number of elements in bytestream, so result array will contain all items from stream + some zero elements at the end. With your code this assumption will lead to exception from Seq.take due to insufficient number of elements

Comment: That's correct. If I remove the Seq.take part... the array takes the right values (although its size is truncated... no main problem). The main problem is that after leaving the ctor the array has size zero! I will add more context to my question now.

Comment: @desco: I updated the answer following the correct assumption.

Comment: Latest code creates an array with total size equal to the sum of thesize plus bytestream size.  Total size should just be "thesize".

Comment: @Benedetto: No, it has `len_bytestream + (thesize - len_bystream) = thesize` elements. I added an explanation to the error you noticed in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
type SomeClass(size, bytes : seq<byte>) = 
    let buf = Array.zeroCreate size
    do
        // Here code assumes that size is always greater than number of items in bytes, is it always correct ?
        Seq.iteri(fun i b -> buf.[i] <- b) bytes
    member this.Buffer = buf

let v = SomeClass(5, (List.init 3 byte))
printfn "%A" v.Buffer // printf [|0uy; 1uy; 2uy; 0uy; 0uy|]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
This code runs and I can see the array properly initialized with the sequence's values. However, after exiting the constructor the array goes back to having all zeros.

Comment: do you see zeros in array with debugger or this value actually contains all zeros if you use it in runtime? With the former - it can be an issue with debugger support